# Custom Tab Bar, with central button which will be hide by pressed index

Tags: swift, animation, tabbar

How I can create Custom tab bar with 4 items and one FAB in center BUT Fab button show only when i press on index 3, for index 0 .. 3 fab.isHidden = true. I am don't need animation that button if shift, but in fill be plus), only show / hide. For creating custom tab bat I am use this guide https://medium.com/better-programming/draw-a-custom-ios-tabbar-shape-27d298a7f4fa, I am need create tab bar like this , I am try ma[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/meBUH.png)ny other way but can't solved problem.

[Custom tab bar which needed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUWTw.png)

I am try this way

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class CustomizedTabBar: UITabBar {

   
    private var shapeLayer: CALayer?

    private func addShape() {
        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.path = createPath()
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = 1.0

        if let oldShapeLayer = self.shapeLayer {
            self.layer.replaceSublayer(oldShapeLayer, with: shapeLayer)
        } else {
            self.layer.insertSublayer(shapeLayer, at: 0)
        }

        self.shapeLayer = shapeLayer
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        self.addShape()
    }

    func createPath() -> CGPath {

        let height: CGFloat = 37.0
        let path = UIBezierPath()
        let centerWidth = self.frame.width / 2

        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)) // start top left
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: (centerWidth - height * 2), y: 0)) // the beginning of the trough

////        // first curve down
//      path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: centerWidth, y: height), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: (centerWidth - 25), y: 0), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: centerWidth - 35, y: height))
//
////        // second curve up
//        path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: (centerWidth + height * 1.0), y: 0),
//                    controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: centerWidth + 25, y: height), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: (centerWidth + 30), y: 0))
        
        // cirle inside tab bar
        path.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: centerWidth, y: 0), radius: height, startAngle: CGFloat(180).degreesToRadians, endAngle: CGFloat(0).degreesToRadians, clockwise: false)
        

        // complete the rect

        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.frame.width, y: 0))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.frame.width, y: self.frame.height))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.frame.height))
        path.close()

        return path.cgPath
    }

    override func point(inside point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
        let buttonRadius: CGFloat = 35
        return abs(self.center.x - point.x) > buttonRadius || abs(point.y) > buttonRadius
    }

    func createPathCircle() -> CGPath {

        let radius: CGFloat = 37.0
        let path = UIBezierPath()
        let centerWidth = self.frame.width / 2

        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: (centerWidth - radius * 2), y: 0))
        path.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: centerWidth, y: 0), radius: radius, startAngle: CGFloat(180).degreesToRadians, endAngle: CGFloat(0).degreesToRadians, clockwise: false)
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.frame.width, y: 0))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.frame.width, y: self.frame.height))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.frame.height))
        path.close()
        return path.cgPath
    }
}

extension CGFloat {
    var degreesToRadians: CGFloat { return self * .pi / 180 }
    var radiansToDegrees: CGFloat { return self * 180 / .pi }
}
```

And second way

```
import UIKit

class MainTabBar: UITabBar {

    var checkState: Bool = true
    
   public var middleButton = UIButton()

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        
        guard let tabItems = items else { return }
        tabItems[1].titlePositionAdjustment = UIOffset(horizontal: -10, vertical: 0)
        tabItems[2].titlePositionAdjustment = UIOffset(horizontal: 10, vertical: 0)

 setupMiddleButton()
        
   
  
    }
    
    override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
        if self.isHidden {
            return super.hitTest(point, with: event)
        }
        
        let from = point
        let to = middleButton.center
        

        return sqrt((from.x - to.x) * (from.x - to.x) + (from.y - to.y) * (from.y - to.y)) <= 39 ? middleButton : super.hitTest(point, with: event)
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        middleButton.center = CGPoint(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2, y: 5)
    }

    func setupMiddleButton() {

        middleButton.frame.size = CGSize(width: 70, height: 70)
        middleButton.layer.cornerRadius = 35
        middleButton.layer.masksToBounds = true
        middleButton.layer.borderWidth = 8
        middleButton.layer.borderColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
        middleButton.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.2447069331, green: 0.850134835, blue: 0.1531122658, alpha: 1)
        middleButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "plus.png"), for: .normal)
        middleButton.center = CGPoint(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2, y: 0)
        middleButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(test), for: .touchUpInside)
       
        addSubview(middleButton)
        
    }

    @objc func test() {
        print("my name is jeff")
    }
    
      

}
```

and I am try this way from article
https://equaleyes.com/blog/2017/09/04/the-common-raised-center-button-problems-in-tabbar/
but it's not working for me, also I am read too many info from WWW and don't get answer(

Comment: what you have tried so far ? post your code

Comment: I am hope this code help solved problem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am was created this tab bar, ours need few steps.
Create ViewController and Embed in "TabBarController", then need create TWO class first for "UITabBar" this class contain shape and what you want with "UITabBar", second class for "UITabBarController" for switch between ViewControllers inside we can add animation.... It's need because, my TabBar have 4 tabs and only on LAST tabs I am have Central FAB button with animation, and I am should animate position of my 2 and 3 ui tab bar element when button is appear.

Class for "UITabBar"

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class CustomizedTabBar: UITabBar {
    
    // MARK:- Variables -
    @objc public var centerButtonActionHandler: ()-> () = {}

    @IBInspectable public var centerButton: UIButton?
    @IBInspectable public var centerButtonColor: UIColor?
    @IBInspectable public var centerButtonHeight: CGFloat = 50.0
    @IBInspectable public var padding: CGFloat = 5.0
    @IBInspectable public var buttonImage: UIImage?
    @IBInspectable public var buttonTitle: String?
    
    @IBInspectable public var tabbarColor: UIColor = UIColor.lightGray
    @IBInspectable public var unselectedItemColor: UIColor = .init(red: 0.58, green: 0.61, blue: 0.66, alpha: 1.0)
    @IBInspectable public var selectedItemColor: UIColor = UIColor.black
    
    public var arc: Bool = true {
        didSet {
            self.setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }
    
    private var shapeLayer: CALayer?

    private func addShape() {
        
        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.path = createPath()
        
        
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        shapeLayer.fillColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.96, green: 0.96, blue: 0.96, alpha: 1)
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = 1.0

        if let oldShapeLayer = self.shapeLayer {
            self.layer.replaceSublayer(oldShapeLayer, with: shapeLayer)
        } else {
            self.layer.insertSublayer(shapeLayer, at: 0)
        }
        
        
        self.shapeLayer = shapeLayer
        self.tintColor = centerButtonColor
        self.unselectedItemTintColor = unselectedItemColor
        self.tintColor = selectedItemColor
        self.setupMiddleButton()
        
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        self.addShape()
    }
    
    override public func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
        guard !clipsToBounds && !isHidden && alpha > 0 else { return nil }
        for member in subviews.reversed() {
            let subPoint = member.convert(point, from: self)
            guard let result = member.hitTest(subPoint, with: event) else { continue }
            return result
        }
        return nil
    }

    func createPath() -> CGPath {

        let padding: CGFloat = 5.0
        let centerButtonHeight: CGFloat = 53.0
        
        let f = CGFloat(centerButtonHeight / 2.0) + padding
        let h = frame.height
        let w = frame.width
        let halfW = frame.width/2.0
        let r = CGFloat(18)
        let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.move(to: .zero)
        
        if (!arc) {
            
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: halfW-f-(r/2.0), y: 0))

            path.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: halfW-f, y: (r/2.0)), controlPoint: CGPoint(x: halfW-f, y: 0))

            path.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: halfW, y: (r/2.0)), radius: f, startAngle: .pi, endAngle: 0, clockwise: false)

            path.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: halfW+f+(r/2.0), y: 0), controlPoint: CGPoint(x: halfW+f, y: 0))
        }
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: w, y: 0))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: w, y: h))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: h))
        path.close()

        return path.cgPath
    }
    
    private func setupMiddleButton() {
        
        centerButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: (self.bounds.width / 2)-(centerButtonHeight/2), y: -16, width: centerButtonHeight, height: centerButtonHeight))
        centerButton!.setNeedsDisplay()
        centerButton!.layer.cornerRadius = centerButton!.frame.size.width / 2.0
        centerButton!.setTitle(buttonTitle, for: .normal)
        centerButton!.setImage(UIImage(named: "plus"), for: .normal)
        centerButton!.backgroundColor = .init(red: 0.07, green: 0.83, blue: 0.05, alpha: 1.0)
        centerButton!.tintColor = UIColor.white

        self.centerButton!.isHidden = true

        if (!self.arc) {

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                
                UIView.transition(with: self.centerButton!, duration: 1,
                    options: .transitionCrossDissolve,
                    animations: {

                        self.centerButton!.isHidden = false

                })
            }
        }
        
        
        //add to the tabbar and add click event
        self.addSubview(centerButton!)
        centerButton!.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.centerButtonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
    }


    override func point(inside point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
        let buttonRadius: CGFloat = 35
        return abs(self.center.x - point.x) > buttonRadius || abs(point.y) > buttonRadius
    }

    func createPathCircle() -> CGPath {

        let radius: CGFloat = 37.0
        let path = UIBezierPath()
        let centerWidth = self.frame.width / 2

        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: (centerWidth - radius * 2), y: 0))
        path.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: centerWidth, y: 0), radius: radius, startAngle: CGFloat(180).degreesToRadians, endAngle: CGFloat(0).degreesToRadians, clockwise: false)
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.frame.width, y: 0))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.frame.width, y: self.frame.height))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.frame.height))
        path.close()
        return path.cgPath
    }
    
    // Menu Button Touch Action
    @objc func centerButtonAction(sender: UIButton) {
       self.centerButtonActionHandler()
    }
    
}

extension CGFloat {
    var degreesToRadians: CGFloat { return self * .pi / 180 }
    var radiansToDegrees: CGFloat { return self * 180 / .pi }
}
```

And class for UITabBarController

import UIKit

```
class MyTabBarController: UITabBarController {
    override func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {
        let myTabBar = tabBar as! CustomizedTabBar
        if (myTabBar.items?[3] == item) {
            myTabBar.arc = false
        } else {
            myTabBar.arc = true
        }
    }
}
```